Google Maps API: Unable to Generate Custom Map Pins using "chart.apis.google.com"
I'm currently working on a project where I need to customize map pins for markers in Google Maps API. I've been using the URL format provided by Google Maps API to generate custom map pins dynamically, but it seems that the URL https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=L|1e90ff|000000 is not working anymore.
Could someone please clarify if this feature has been deprecated or if there's an alternative method to achieve custom map pins with Google Maps API?
Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions!

Just been hit by this today too. Our workaround was to use svg:
var icon = {
    path: "M-20,0a20,20 0 1,0 40,0a20,20 0 1,0 -40,0",
    fillColor: "#FFCC00",
    fillOpacity: 1,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: 0.5
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: loclatlong[i],
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});


Thank you for your response, but with your code, it generates a circle, not a marker.

You can find svg values for different marker shapes online fairly easily, I wanted to show the logic of whats happening without overwhelming the answer with a 300 character svg path
For example: https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/506670/pin if you download the svg and examine the file, you can see:
"M16.001 5c-4.216 0-7.714 3.418-7.634 7.634.029 1.578.719 2.824 1.351 4.024.242.461 6.264 10.332 6.264 10.332V27l.001-.007.002.007v-.01l6.531-10.377c.407-.703.793-1.771.793-1.771A7.631 7.631 0 0 0 16.001 5zM16 16.019a3.895 3.895 0 0 1-3.896-3.897A3.898 3.898 0 1 1 16 16.019z"

Was also hit by this a few days ago. Switched to using AdvancedMarkerElements. They support custom colours, borders etc. Sample below:
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(element.Latitude, element.Longitude);

        var marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: latlong,
            title: 'Title here',
        });

        var pinBackground = new google.maps.marker.PinElement({
            background: '#BackgroundColor',
            glyphColor: '#CenterCircleColuor',
            borderColor: '#BorderColour',
            scale: 0.8, //Size of the marker
        });


        marker.content = pinBackground.element;
        marker.setMap(yourMap);

